# Cuadrar los elementos de un formulario HTML

Tags: html, html5

Mi nombre es Bernardo y ando aprendiendo HTML5 desde cero,

Ahora estoy haciendo un ejercicio básico de hacer un formulario mediante elementos semánticos y me encuentro con un problema: no sé por qué las dos últimas secciones ("Gestión de reserva" y "Pie de página" no me aparecen debajo de la que deberían estar ("Formulario de Reserva").

De las causas que barajo es que no debería usar fieldsets y cabeceras  en la sección "Formulario de Reserva", aunque no le encuentro mucha lógica a que no se pueda hacer...

¿qué opináis?

Luego en estas dos secciones que os comento querría seguir metiendo cosas

Os dejo el código a ver si encontráis la causa,

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano,

```html
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Playas Reservas</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <style>
            *{
                margin: 0;
            }
            
            #cabeceraDelDocumento{
                width: 100%;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: aquamarine;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            #menuHorizontal{
                width: 100%;
                height: 35px;
                background-color: azure;
            }
            
            /*Los elementos dentro del #menuHorizontal del tipo <a> hacemos que tengan un determinado
            formato. Esto es un anclaje de elementos*/
            #menuHorizontal > a{
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            
            #menuVertical{
                width: 15%;
                background-color: beige;
                height: 200px;
                float: left;
            }
            
            #playasInfo{
                width: 85%; /*para que ocupe el 70% de la pantalla y permita tener elementos al lado*/
                height: 200px;
                float: left;
            }
            
            iframe{
                position: relative;
                border:none;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            #formularioReserva{
                width: 85%; /*para que ocupe el 70% de la pantalla y permita tener elementos al lado*/
                height: 270px; /*270px;*/
                float: left;
                margin-left: 129px;
            }
            
            #gestionReserva{
                width: 85%;
                height: 22px;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 129px;
            }
            
            #pieDePagina{
                width: 85%;
                height: 5px;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 129px;
            }
            
        </style>
        
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <!--Solución del profesor al problema 1 sobre un formulario de reservas de playas.
        Se utiliza un elemento iframe para mostrar cada una de las playas-->
        
        <header id="cabeceraDelDocumento">
            <h1>Reserva en Playas de España</h1>
        </header>
        
        <!--Barra de navegación: los vamos a poner como enlaces, por eso ponemos ancla y href-->
        <nav id="menuHorizontal">
            <a href="#menuVertical">Playas</a>
            
            <!--El siguiente enlace queda por hacer: TODO "COMPLETAR EL LINK SIGUIENTE CON EL ID DE LA 
            SESIÓN DESTINADA A LA GESTIÓN DE RESERVAS, ES DECIR, DONDE APARECE LA TABLA"-->
            <a href="">Gestionar Reservas</a>
        </nav>
        
        <nav id="menuVertical">
            <h3>Playas Disponibles</h3> <!--Las ponemos en una lista no ordenada -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="playa1.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="playa2.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="playa3.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="playa4.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="playa5.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 5</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </nav>
        
        <section id="playasInfo">
            <iframe seamless src="playa1.html" name="iframeContainer" 
                    sandbox=""></iframe>
        </section>
        
        <!--Sección del formulario de reserva-->
        <section id="formularioReserva">
        <fieldset>
        <h2>Formulario de Reserva</h2>
         
                <label for="reserveSuPlaya">Reserve su Playa</label>
                <input list="playas" name="playas">
                    <datalist id="playas">
                        <option value="Playa 1">
                        <option value="Playa 2">
                        <option value="Playa 3">
                        <option value="Playa 4">
                        <option value="Playa 5">
                    </datalist>
                
                <fieldset>
                <h3>Datos Personales</h3>
                <h4>Nombre y Apellidos</h4>
                <form method="GET" action="index.html" name="datosPersonales">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                    <input id="nombre" 
                           type="text" 
                           name="nombreDelCliente" 
                           placeholder="Escriba su nombre" required>
                    
                    <label for="apellido1">Primer Apellido: </label>
                    <input id="apellido1" 
                           type="text" 
                           name="apellido1DelCliente" 
                           placeholder="Escriba su apellido" required>
                    
                    <label for="apellido2">Segundo Apellido: </label>
                    <input id="apellido2" 
                           type="text" 
                           name="apellido2DelCliente" 
                           placeholder="Escriba su apellido" required>
                    
                    <h4>Identificación</h4>
                    <label for="identificacion">Seleccione tipo de documento:</label>
                    
                    <label for="dni">DNI: </label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="identifDNINIE" 
                           value="DNI" 
                           id="identificacionDNI" checked>
                    
                    <label for="nie">NIE: </label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="identifDNINIE" 
                           value="NIE" 
                           id="identificacionNIE" checked>
                    
                    <label for="numeroDocumento">Número del documento: </label>
                    <input id="numeroDocumento" 
                           type="text" 
                           name="numeroDocumento" 
                           placeholder="Escriba su documento" required>
                    
                    <h4>Teléfono</h4>
                    <label for="telefonoMovil">Teléfono móvil: </label>
                    <input id="telefonoMovil" 
                           type="number" 
                           name="telefonoMovil" 
                           placeholder="Número móvil" required>
                    
                    <label for="telefonoFijo">Teléfono fijo: </label>
                    <input id="telefonoFijo" 
                           type="number" 
                           name="telefonoFijo" 
                           placeholder="Número fijo">
                    
                    <h4>Correo electrónico</h4>
                    <label for="correoElectronico">Correo Electrónico: </label>
                    <input id="correoElectronico" 
                           type="email" 
                           name="correoElectronico" 
                           placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
                 </fieldset>
                
                <fieldset>   
                    <h4>Datos de llegada</h4>
                    <label for="fechaEntrada">Fecha de Entrada: </label>
                    <input id="fechaEntrada" 
                           type="date" 
                           name="fechaEntrada" 
                           placeholder="Introduzca la fecha de entrada" required>
                    
                    <label for="horaEntrada">Hora de entrada: </label>
                    <input id="horaEntrada" 
                           type="time" 
                           name="horaEntrada" 
                           placeholder="Introduzca hora de ingreso">
                    <br>
                    
                    <label for="fechaSalida">Fecha de salida: </label>
                    <input id="fechaSalida" 
                           type="date" 
                           name="fechaSalida" 
                           placeholder="Introduzca la fecha de salida" required>
                </fieldset>
                    
                <fieldset>
                    <h4>Otros datos</h4>
                    <h5>Hijos menores de edad</h5>
                    <label for="hijosMenores">¿Tiene hijos menores?: </label>
                    
                    <label for="afirmativo1">Sí: </label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="afirmNegativo1" 
                           value="Sí" 
                           id="afirmativo1" checked>
                    
                    <label for="negativo1">No: </label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="afirmNegativo1" 
                           value="No" 
                           id="negativo1" checked>
                    
                    <label for="numeroHijos">¿Cuántos?: </label>
                    <input id="numeroHijos" 
                           type="number" 
                           name="numeroHijos" 
                           placeholder="Introduzca número menores de edad">
                    <br>
                    
                    <h5>Animales de compañía</h5>
                    <label for="animalesCompañía">Va a ir con animales de compañía?: </label>
                    <label for="afirmativo2">Sí: </label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="afirmNegativo2" 
                           value="Sí" 
                           id="afirmativo2" checked>
                    
                    <label for="negativo2">No: </label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="afirmNegativo2" 
                           value="No" 
                           id="negativo2" checked>
                    
                    <label for="indicarAnimal">Indicar animal de compañía: </label>
                    <input list="animalesCompañía" name="animalesCompañía">
                    <datalist id="animalesCompañía">
                        <option value="Perro">
                        <option value="Gato">
                        <option value="Otros">
                    </datalist>
                    <p><b>NOTA: Se hará precio adicional en caso de perro de raza peligrosa y animal exótico</b></p>
                </fieldset>    
                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario">     
                </fieldset>
        </section>
        
        <!--Sección para la gestión de la reserva-->
        <section id="gestionReserva">
            <!--De momento es una tabla vacía-->
            <h3>Gestión de Reservas</h3>
            
        </section>
        
        
        <!--Pie de página-->
        <footer id="pieDePagina">
            <p>Información de contacto,
                    a través de un mapa Google, etc.</p>
        </footer>
        
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás 'forzando' a que el ID #formularioReserva tenga un height especifico de 270px, haciendo que se sobreponga los demás elementos por que aunque tu 'fuerces' el height a un valor especifico sigue habiendo información que quieres mostrar, y el navegador lo que hace es mostrarlo como pueda, y por eso se sobre encima.

Lo único que tienes que hacer es quitar en tu CSS en #formularioReserva el height y listo.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Playas Reservas</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
        }

        #cabeceraDelDocumento{
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: aquamarine;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #menuHorizontal{
            width: 100%;
            height: 35px;
            background-color: azure;
        }

        /*Los elementos dentro del #menuHorizontal del tipo <a> hacemos que tengan un determinado
        formato. Esto es un anclaje de elementos*/
        #menuHorizontal > a{
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #menuVertical{
            width: 15%;
            background-color: beige;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
        }

        #playasInfo{
            width: 85%; /*para que ocupe el 70% de la pantalla y permita tener elementos al lado*/
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
        }

        iframe{
            position: relative;
            border:none;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #formularioReserva{
            width: 85%; /*para que ocupe el 70% de la pantalla y permita tener elementos al lado*/
             /*270px;*/
            float: left;
            margin-left: 129px;
        }

        #gestionReserva{
            width: 85%;
            height: 22px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 129px;
        }

        #pieDePagina{
            width: 85%;
            height: 5px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 129px;
        }

    </style>

</head>


<body>
    <!--Solución del profesor al problema 1 sobre un formulario de reservas de playas.
    Se utiliza un elemento iframe para mostrar cada una de las playas-->

    <header id="cabeceraDelDocumento">
        <h1>Reserva en Playas de España</h1>
    </header>

    <!--Barra de navegación: los vamos a poner como enlaces, por eso ponemos ancla y href-->
    <nav id="menuHorizontal">
        <a href="#menuVertical">Playas</a>

        <!--El siguiente enlace queda por hacer: TODO "COMPLETAR EL LINK SIGUIENTE CON EL ID DE LA 
        SESIÓN DESTINADA A LA GESTIÓN DE RESERVAS, ES DECIR, DONDE APARECE LA TABLA"-->
        <a href="">Gestionar Reservas</a>
    </nav>

    <nav id="menuVertical">
        <h3>Playas Disponibles</h3> <!--Las ponemos en una lista no ordenada -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="playa1.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="playa2.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="playa3.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="playa4.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="playa5.html" target="iframeContainer">Playa 5</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>

    <section id="playasInfo">
        <iframe seamless src="playa1.html" name="iframeContainer" 
                sandbox=""></iframe>
    </section>

    <!--Sección del formulario de reserva-->
    <section id="formularioReserva">
      <fieldset>
        <h2>Formulario de Reserva</h2>

            <label for="reserveSuPlaya">Reserve su Playa</label>
            <input list="playas" name="playas">
                <datalist id="playas">
                    <option value="Playa 1">
                    <option value="Playa 2">
                    <option value="Playa 3">
                    <option value="Playa 4">
                    <option value="Playa 5">
                </datalist>

            <fieldset>
            <h3>Datos Personales</h3>
            <h4>Nombre y Apellidos</h4>
            <form method="GET" action="index.html" name="datosPersonales">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input id="nombre" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="nombreDelCliente" 
                       placeholder="Escriba su nombre" required>

                <label for="apellido1">Primer Apellido: </label>
                <input id="apellido1" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="apellido1DelCliente" 
                       placeholder="Escriba su apellido" required>

                <label for="apellido2">Segundo Apellido: </label>
                <input id="apellido2" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="apellido2DelCliente" 
                       placeholder="Escriba su apellido" required>

                <h4>Identificación</h4>
                <label for="identificacion">Seleccione tipo de documento:</label>

                <label for="dni">DNI: </label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="identifDNINIE" 
                       value="DNI" 
                       id="identificacionDNI" checked>

                <label for="nie">NIE: </label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="identifDNINIE" 
                       value="NIE" 
                       id="identificacionNIE" checked>

                <label for="numeroDocumento">Número del documento: </label>
                <input id="numeroDocumento" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="numeroDocumento" 
                       placeholder="Escriba su documento" required>

                <h4>Teléfono</h4>
                <label for="telefonoMovil">Teléfono móvil: </label>
                <input id="telefonoMovil" 
                       type="number" 
                       name="telefonoMovil" 
                       placeholder="Número móvil" required>

                <label for="telefonoFijo">Teléfono fijo: </label>
                <input id="telefonoFijo" 
                       type="number" 
                       name="telefonoFijo" 
                       placeholder="Número fijo">

                <h4>Correo electrónico</h4>
                <label for="correoElectronico">Correo Electrónico: </label>
                <input id="correoElectronico" 
                       type="email" 
                       name="correoElectronico" 
                       placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
             </fieldset>

            <fieldset>   
                <h4>Datos de llegada</h4>
                <label for="fechaEntrada">Fecha de Entrada: </label>
                <input id="fechaEntrada" 
                       type="date" 
                       name="fechaEntrada" 
                       placeholder="Introduzca la fecha de entrada" required>

                <label for="horaEntrada">Hora de entrada: </label>
                <input id="horaEntrada" 
                       type="time" 
                       name="horaEntrada" 
                       placeholder="Introduzca hora de ingreso">
                <br>

                <label for="fechaSalida">Fecha de salida: </label>
                <input id="fechaSalida" 
                       type="date" 
                       name="fechaSalida" 
                       placeholder="Introduzca la fecha de salida" required>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <h4>Otros datos</h4>
                <h5>Hijos menores de edad</h5>
                <label for="hijosMenores">¿Tiene hijos menores?: </label>

                <label for="afirmativo1">Sí: </label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="afirmNegativo1" 
                       value="Sí" 
                       id="afirmativo1" checked>

                <label for="negativo1">No: </label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="afirmNegativo1" 
                       value="No" 
                       id="negativo1" checked>

                <label for="numeroHijos">¿Cuántos?: </label>
                <input id="numeroHijos" 
                       type="number" 
                       name="numeroHijos" 
                       placeholder="Introduzca número menores de edad">
                <br>

                <h5>Animales de compañía</h5>
                <label for="animalesCompañía">Va a ir con animales de compañía?: </label>
                <label for="afirmativo2">Sí: </label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="afirmNegativo2" 
                       value="Sí" 
                       id="afirmativo2" checked>

                <label for="negativo2">No: </label>
                <input type="radio" 
                       name="afirmNegativo2" 
                       value="No" 
                       id="negativo2" checked>

                <label for="indicarAnimal">Indicar animal de compañía: </label>
                <input list="animalesCompañía" name="animalesCompañía">
                <datalist id="animalesCompañía">
                    <option value="Perro">
                    <option value="Gato">
                    <option value="Otros">
                </datalist>
                <p><b>NOTA: Se hará precio adicional en caso de perro de raza peligrosa y animal exótico</b></p>
            </fieldset>    

                <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario">     
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <!--Sección para la gestión de la reserva-->
    <section id="gestionReserva">
        <!--De momento es una tabla vacía-->
        <h3>Gestión de Reservas</h3>

    </section>


    <!--Pie de página-->
    <footer id="pieDePagina">
        <p>Información de contacto,
                a través de un mapa Google, etc.</p>
    </footer>

</body>


</html>
```